# "I couldn't but laugh" - correct or not?

Tags: word-choice

Is the usage of  "I couldn't but laugh" in place of "I couldn't not laugh" correct English? Or should it always be "I couldn't help but laugh"?

Comment: *I couldn't help but laugh* is a double negative, and strictly means I did not laugh. It is often used to mean the opposite.

Comment: @TimLymington are you sure? `I couldn't help but laugh` to me means exactly what Daniel Harbour said in his answer - I could not help laughing.

Comment: Simple analysis: *I could not but laugh* = *I couldn't help laughing*. *I couldn't help but laugh* must mean the opposite (though it is so commonly used the other way it may have become idiomatic).

Comment: Except that this is the [NPI idiom _can help_ + `V`-_ing_,](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) which requires a negative environment to flower. _Cannot/Couldn't but (to)_ `VP` is [a "Nobbut" construction](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf), using the 'except' sense of _but_ -- _none but the brave, nothing but the best_ --

Comment: @JohnLawler: clarify please. I said that *cannot but laugh* is a normal phrase, meaning the same as *can't help laughing*; you seem to agree. If so, *cannot but help* is *can not not not laugh* which equals *not laugh*. Grammatical rules do not come into it.

Comment: Let's just say that English isn't a commutative field, so you can't count on composing [negatives](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) like multiplying negative numbers. [It's logic that represents language](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), after all, not the other way round.

Comment: The contraction is inappropriate.  "I could not (or perhaps *naught*) but laugh" is archaic but "legal".

Comment: Note that the original expression may well have been "I could naught but laugh", which, de-archaicized, means "I could do nothing but laugh."

Answer (score 9):

*I couldn’t but laugh* means *All I could do was laugh*, implying that there was no practical action I could have undertaken (or, at least, that’s how older members of my family use it; it’s outmoded for me and I don’t use it).

By contrast, *I couldn’t not laugh* means *I couldn’t help laughing*, *I had to laugh*.

So, the two sentences are not equivalent and shouldn’t be interchangeable.

The third sentence, *I couldn’t help but laugh* means the same as *I couldn’t not laugh*.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example of a poet who has made millions laugh, and say: *I could not but laugh*

[The Purist

by Ogden Nash](https://westegg.com/nash/purist.html)

I give you now Professor Twist,

A conscientious scientist,

Trustees exclaimed, "He never bungles!"

And sent him off to distant jungles.

Camped on a tropic riverside,

One day he missed his loving bride.

She had, the guide informed him later,

Been eaten by an alligator.

Professor Twist **could not but smile**.

"You mean," he said, "a crocodile."

(emphasis added)

Answer (score -1):

"I couldn't but laugh", "I couldn't help but laugh" and "I couldn't laugh" are not the same in meaning. The first two means the same - "I had no other option than laughing"; whereas the last sentence means plainly "Nothing made me laugh, and so I was not laughing."

---

Just an addition (Out of context) - 
"I have no doubt but that he is a cheater" - Here in this sentence "but" doesn't act the way it acted in previous case. Here this sentence mean "I had no doubt that he is a cheater"

Comment: Slight oversight in your answer: the questioner was asking about “I couldn't _not_ laugh”.  (Are the first two really equivalent for you??)

Comment: I was looking your reply. I agree about the explanation you gave about the two sentences except this one - "I couldn't laugh". I can't get the explanation that "I couldn't laugh" means "I couldn't help laughing, I had to laugh". and did you mean "I couldn't help but laugh" and "I couldn't but laugh" are the same in meaning?

Comment: @Man_From_India none of the question states `I couldn't laugh` - are you getting it confused with `I couldn't NOT laugh`?

Comment: @Man_From_India  I think that you are wrong as regards the second example you give. 'I have no doubt but that he is a cheater' literally means that his being a cheater is the only doubt you have. So you are effectively saying you doubt that he is a cheater, not the opposite.

Comment: From Macmillan dictionary - 
"no doubt but that" = used for emphasizing that something is certain. 
"I couldn't go to your place because I was down with fever" - Here it means that I was not able to pay you a visit.
Same explanation I will use to explain "I couldn't laugh". Say for example "I couldn't laugh at his cheap jokes".
"I couldn't not laugh" - literally means "I laughed", but sometimes people make it out this way "I couldn't laugh".